# Android C2DM Wont register

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have used [This guide](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.c2dm/codestartpage.html). But if i add it to another project, i dont receive anything:
I have made changes to the manifest so it matches the guide(I think):

Question: But now i dont get any response to my registration attempt.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.vogella.android.c2dm" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <permission android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="RegisterActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.C2DMReceiver" />

        <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is 
            not set - any other app can generate it -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="ResultActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How to start registering (Have checked that it reaches into the if condition)(is called from C2DM2Activity):

```
public void checkRegistered() {
        String registered = C2DMessaging
                .getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        if (registered.equals("")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "starting registration of C2DM");
            C2DMessaging.register(this, C2DMID);
        }
    }
```

Filestructure:

[image: Filestructure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code part. C2DMBaseReceiver, there is a place where it defines the C2DMReceiver to be in the application package default folder.

Thanks to all others for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

What if you add a '.' to your service name, I think that's the way it should be.

Try this `<service android:name=".c2dm.C2DMReceiver" />`

Comment: In LogCat, do you get a message like 'Receiver not found' or something? When you try to register

Comment: Nope i didn't
I answered my own question above you, else thanks for the attempt, it was probably also a bi-cause, so ill +1 u :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
```

To

```
android:name="dk.lector.cms.c2dm.YourReceiverClassName"
```

Comment: That is my broadcastreceiver :-)

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment above that `C2DMBroadcastReceiver` is your receiver. Then what is with the `C2DMReceiver` that I see in your `de.vogella.android.c2dm` package?

And you question is about how to start registering. In the tutorial under section **2.2. Getting the registration ID for the mobile app** there is a `register` method that needs to be called. When the *registrationId* comes back from the Google server it is caught in your receiver's `onReceive`. In his tutorial, the receiver for registering is `C2DMRegistrationReceiver`. If you say that `C2DMBroadcastReceiver` is your receiver and you are sure about that, just call *register* and the `onReceive` should receive the message.

Also, you should try posting the entire Manifest.xml. Make sure you are using the permission for INTERNET and a custom permission like:

```
<permission
    android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.simpleclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.simpleclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: It is because it is not the simplereceiver i have chosen, i have taken his more elaborate one, from his source codes.
And it works fine, when it is purely his, but if I try to implement his in my own project, then everything stops sending.
I'll try registering it anyways, but it shouldnt be needed, since im doing it from the manifest.
Manifest updated, to display everything, it was a display error here on site else it'd been here from beginning

Comment: You are not **registering** from the manifest. You are just declaring the receiver that handles the registration broadcast. The proper registration is done through the `register` method, which issues a registration call to the Google servers.

Comment: That is definitively not correct.
Quote:"An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However, since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a component before it can launch that component, intent filters are generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) as <intent-filter> elements. (The one exception would be filters for broadcast receivers that are registered dynamically by calling Context.registerReceiver(); they are directly created as IntentFilter objects.)".

Answer (score 0):

The package name u got registered with `C2DM` is it same as other project you transfered because for C2DM  it identify an app with its `Package` name

Comment: No it isn't. So do i need to make a new C2DM account for this?
Really thought that it was just attached to my email, and then i could unregister it in 1 project, and register it in another?

Comment: Tried making new accounts, for this, but still no luck :(
And btw. the first account which worked under the directly C/P'ed project, wasn't registered with that package, so not really sure they sure it for anything.

Comment: i am sure for this your package name must be registered

Comment: From what I have tested, it really doesn't make a difference, though thanks a lot for your effort to fix my problem.